# the max value Less than

Tags: sql

I have a table as follows. I need to search for something right less than an array of variable e.g. 103000, 104000, 105000, 106000. Now I repeat one simple command for each variable in the array. Is there any way I can use a single command for all results?

Table data:

```
[time] 
 102700
 103500
 104700
 105300
```

```sql
Select max(time) as [time] from [DB_NAME] WHERE [Time] < 103000  ====> Return 102700
Select max(time) as [time] from [DB_NAME] WHERE [Time] < 104000  ====> Return 103500
Select max(time) as [time] from [DB_NAME] WHERE [Time] < 105000  ====> Return 104700
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways, depending on what you want.  I might suggest:

```
select v.t, max(time) as [time]
from (values (102700), (104000), (105000)
     ) v(t) left join
     [DB_NAME] d
     on d.[time] < v.t
group by v.t;
```

This uses the `values()` table constructor.  Not all databases support that; if not you can use something like `select . . . union all`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this using conditional aggregation :

```
select max(case when [Time] < 103000  then [time] end),
       max(case when [Time] < 104000  then [time] end),
       max(case when [Time] < 105000  then [time] end)
```